# vue.js - conditions and custom filter

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use 3 conditions to display several texts to a tooltip with bootstrap.

```
 <span class="icon icon-info"
  data-toggle="tooltip-click"
  data-placement="right"
  data-trigger="focus hover"
  v-bind:data-original-title="
    condition1 ?
        condition2 ?
           'some.key.id' | customFilter : 'some.key.id2' | customFilter
    :
        condition3 ?
            'some.key.id3' | customFilter : 'some.key.id4' | customFilter
   "
  data-html="true">
</span>
```

And it throw this exception

[image]

What did I do wrong?

**Edit:**

I'm working on VueJs 1, and my customFilter is working well individually

```
<span class="icon icon-info"
  data-toggle="tooltip-click"
  data-placement="right"
  data-trigger="focus hover"
  v-bind:data-original-title="'some.key.id' | customFilter"
  data-html="true">
</span>
```

Comment: Filters should come after the final value, like `(condition1?...: "lastvalue") | customFilter`

Comment: I think for something that complex it should be a compute instead of a filter

Comment: Use compute or method. This is much too much logic in template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using Vue 2 but if you are then it has moved away from using custom filters, check out:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters

What you posted looks messy. I would recommend moving this logic into a computed property.

Comment: I'm still on Vue.js 1
In fact my customFilter is working well. If I use it without confitions

Comment: Even in Vue 1 due to the layered conditions I'd assume the template parser will start to have issues with what you posted. Therefore I'd recommend a computed property for this, you could then perhaps just apply the final customFilter to the output of the computed property, i.e. `v-bind:data-original-title="computedOriginalTitle | customFilter"